# Remove Paragraph Error

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having a hard time.  I have a document, which is a series of Paragraphs and Tables.  Sometimes, I need to remove the last paragraph of the document and I would like to do so without leaving any empty whitespace.

Currently, I am getting this error:

> Can't remove the last paragraph in a document section.

Does anyone know why this is happening?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: Seems to be related to https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1489  You should add your experience to the issue and star it to receive feedback.

Comment: You might want to create a new issue of the type of the type:defect as the one above was an enhancement request.

Comment: Note that I was able to repro this and reported it as an issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186306083

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach, it seems to work as expected, at least I didn't succeed to make it fail ;-)

```
function deleteAllParagraphs() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  doc.insertParagraph(0, '');// insert a dummy paragraph at the beginning of the doc that we are going to let there
  doc.appendParagraph('');// append another dummy in case doc is empty
  for(var p=doc.getNumChildren();p>=0;p--){
    try{
      doc.getChild(p).removeFromParent();
    }catch(e){}
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT :** from the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1489) I found a better code suggested by #11 cyberaxe
that I slightly modified :

```
function emptyDocument() {
  var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = document.getBody();
  body.appendParagraph('');// to be sure to delete the last paragraph in case it doesn't end with a cr/lf
  while (body.getNumChildren() > 1) body.removeChild( body.getChild( 0 ) );
}
```

Comment: Hello.  Thank you for your reply.

I'm wondering how I can use this in my initial problem?  This seems like it's getting rid of EVERYTHING in a document.  Am I reading the code wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Super late to the party, but it doesn't look like this issue is resolved yet. I used the clear and merge functions to remove any whitespace only paragraphs at the end.

```
var paragraphs = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs();
for (var i=paragraphs.length-1; i>=0; i--){
      var line = paragraphs[i];   
      if (line.getText().trim() ) {
        break;
      }
      else {
        line.clear();
        line.merge();
      }
    }
```